# Pa11y throwing Timeout

Tags: pa11y

I wanted to try pa11y locally before implementing it on my actual project.
heres what I did

pre-requisite: nodejs is installed

1. create a fresh folder
2. execute: npm install -g pa11y
3. tried to test "pa11y https://mail.google.com"

I am receiving timeout error .

I also tried pa11y.json as suggested in one of the github issue. But, I suppose I am missing something more.

[output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVWTn.png)

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

@Soumya try with below configurations,

```
const pa11y = require('pa11y');
const config = {
    wait: 100000,
    timeout: 100000,
    actions: [
        'action 1',
        'action 2'
   ]
 }

 pa11y('https://mail.google.com"', config).then((results) => {
     console.log(results)
 });
```

Timeout is a value which is calculated not only for actions but from the initial start till results generated. By default it is set to 30000 which is quite low to invoke pa11y and run all the actions.

Hope this answer will help.

Thanks

Comment: Increasing the timeout value worked for me.